# converting hyperlink to text

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfsavecontent variable="s">
     <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter</a> 
    </cfsavecontent>
<cfset myStr = REReplaceNoCase(s, "(\bhttp://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+)", "<a href=""http://\1"">""\1""</a>", "all") />
#mystr#
</cfoutput>
```

Output:

http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter

how to get

http://www.cnn.com

Comment: Use a HTML parser, e.g. [jSoup](http://jsoup.org).